# Register global custom directive for cypress component testing in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

Is there way register global custom directive for cypress component testing in vue. Just register with

```
app.directive('some',(el,binding)=>{{...})
```

in main.js file can't solve problem. Because in the component testing component failed resolve that directive.

Local register like that:

```
mount(SomeComp,{
directive:{
  'some': {...}
})
```

isn't good option. Because i use this directive in every component and need local register in every component.

How i can register global directive for cypress component testing ?

Thanxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own mount,

```js
import { mount } from '@cypress/vue'

export const mountWithDirective = (myComponent) => {

  return mount(myComponent, {
    directive:{
      'some': {...}
  })
}
```

Put it in /cypress/support/index.js or another file of your choosing.

```js
// test
import { mountWithDirective } from 'cypress/support'
import Component from './Component.vue'

it...
  mountWithDirective(Component)
```